# How can I create an Asciidoc table of contents from external files?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

The Asciidoc `:toc:` command creates a nicely formatted table of contents from the headings in the document:

```
:toc:

= Part 1

= Part 2

= Part 3
```

[image]

But I want my table of contents to link to other documents, instead of pulling from the document itself:

```
link:part1.adoc[Part 1]

link:part2.adoc[Part 2]

link:part3.adoc[Part 3]
```

Is there a way to create a TOC from links to other files? If not, what styles/blocks/whatever can I use to mimic the style of the TOC as closely as possible?

Comment: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2776

Answer (score 2):

Yes, however, it may not behave the way you intend.

```
= Document
:toc:

== link:part1.adoc[Part 1]

== link:part2.adoc[Part 2]

== link:part3.adoc[Part 3]
```

That produces a table of contents, but its links point to the headings in the same file: that's what the `:toc:` is for. The headings themselves are links to the other documents.

You can create your own list, but to approximate the styling of the on-page TOC, you need to create a `docinfo.html` file containing the CSS you'd like to use:

```
<style>
.mytoc ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.mytoc li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

and specify that you want to use the `docinfo` file:

```
= Document
:docinfo: shared

[.mytoc]
== Table of Contents

* link:part1.adoc[Part 1]

* link:part2.adoc[Part 2]

* link:part3.adoc[Part 3]
```

Note that the styles I included aren't a comprehensive recreation of the the on-page TOC's styles, but hopefully they are enough to show you the way.

See https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file for more information on `docinfo` files.